# Orchard Rename Content Type in Migration

Tags: orchardcms

I'm hoping to rename an existing custom content type in one of my Orchard modules. Is it possible to do this in a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not by using `ContentDefinitionManager`. The simplest way would be to execute an SQL update query against `Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord` table using `SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to try this. Do you know offhand if there are any other places in the database that will need to be renamed? For example, is the default content part created for the type something that has to be renamed somehow?