# Sql to Rename Orchard Custom Content Type

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I'm planning to rename one of my custom content types, so that I can free up its name for a new Orchard module I am working on. I'm hoping to use Schema.ExecuteSql in a migration class as suggested [by this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005369/20489), but I want to make sure I know all of the updates I will need to do.

So far, I understand that I need to update fields in the following tables:

- Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord
- Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord
- Settings_ContentPartDefinitionRecord

Also, here is my general plan for the update SQL I will need to run:

```
DECLARE @From VARCHAR(50) = 'OriginalName'
DECLARE @To VARCHAR(50) = 'NewName'

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

    UPDATE [Current_Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord]
    SET [Name] = @To
    WHERE [Name] = @From

    UPDATE [Current_Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord]
    SET [Name] = @To, [DisplayName] = @To
    WHERE [Name] = @From

    UPDATE [dbo].[Current_Settings_ContentPartDefinitionRecord]
    SET [Name] = @To + 'Part'
    WHERE [Name] = @From + 'Part'

    --COMMIT TRANSACTION
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION /*Rollback while testing*/
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Is there anything else I am missing that will need to be renamed to fully rename my content type?

Comment: Is this really necessary? It sounds dangerous. You can always change the display name of a content type

Comment: I plan to use my newer plugin for multiple sites of mine and want to let the content type become the one I use going forward. For that reason, I don't want to have to rename it in my new version.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Did you try it?

Comment: The data change seemed to work ok, but it appears that there is now a mismatch with my content part class / record names and the text name stored in the db, which effectively orphans access to the content part. Also my content part table still bears the old name Current_XXX_XXX_XXXPartRecord. Guess I'm wondering if I should just name my new type something else rather than go through the pain of deprecating the old.

Comment: Did you get a way trough this? I'm faciing the same situation-

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a way that I trusted enough to go with.

Comment: After battling with this problem for quite a while in different projects, the easiest solution for me was always to use the import/export feature of orchard and simply modify the xml. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer to your problem, but - although it has annecdotal character - it might help you find the solution.

I was working on a Orchard site that had

- a lot of pages
- a lot of html links to other pages on the site
- a lot of custom link items in the navigations (to link to certain anchors inside a target page, etc.)

Shortly before we planned to delpoy the website, it was decided to change the URLs of the most prominent pages for SEO reasons from `http://www.example.org/orchard/products/category-name/product-name`to `http://www.example.org/orchard/shop/category-name/product-name-keyword-anotherkeyword`(gotta love SEO...)

Doing this manually would have taken ages. Changing the URL in the content item itself would be easy (but doing that on ~20 items still would take some time), but changing all those `<a href`s in all the 120+ content items, and all the custom links in the 5 navigations (5 languages) would simply be impossible.

So the only feasable way seemed to be database manipulation.

I used `MS SQL Server Management Studio` to export all tables in the Orchard database to individual .sql files. I then used `Notepad++` to search for all files that contained the partial string `/products/category/product-name` and wrote down the table names and the field name (usually `Text` or `Data`)

In this case the results were in the following tables:

- Common_BodyPartRecord.Table
- Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord
- Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord

To `search-replace` a partial string in SQl you use the `replace` function, and because of the datatype of the table fields the orchard stores the data in you have to cast strings. The resulting SQL queries look like this:

```
update [Orchard_Live].[dbo].[Common_BodyPartRecord] 
    set Text = cast(replace(cast(Text as nvarchar(max)),     N'/products/category/product-name', N'/shop/category-name/product-name-keyword-anotherkeyword') as ntext)
where cast(Text as nvarchar(max)) LIKE N'%/products/category/product-name%'

update [Orchard_Live].[dbo].[Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord] 
set Data = cast(replace(cast(Data as nvarchar(max)), N'/products/category/product-name', N'/shop/category-name/product-name-keyword-anotherkeyword') as ntext)
where cast(Data as nvarchar(max)) LIKE N'%/products/category/product-name%'

update [Orchard_Live].[dbo].[Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord] 
set Data = cast(replace(cast(Data as nvarchar(max)), N'/products/category/product-name', N'/shop/category-name/product-name-keyword-anotherkeyword') as ntext)
where cast(Data as nvarchar(max)) LIKE N'%/products/category/product-name%'
```

I had to do this for every URL that had to be changed. Took quite a while, but still beat manually changing everything by far. Maybe this "workflow" can help with your problem, too.